# Angular Cloudinary width not working when using variables

Tags: angular, cloudinary

I have an issue with using [Cloudinary with Angular](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/angular_image_manipulation).
If I add a simple image like this:

```
<cl-image class="img-fluid" [public-id]="brand.image.publicId" dpr="auto" crop="scale">
    <cl-placeholder type="pixelate">
    </cl-placeholder>
    <cl-transformation quality="auto" fetch-format="auto" width="500">
    </cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

This works fine.
If I try then to add a width:

```
<cl-image class="img-fluid" [public-id]="brand.image.publicId" dpr="auto" crop="scale">
    <cl-placeholder type="pixelate">
    </cl-placeholder>
    <cl-transformation width="150" crop="thumb">
    </cl-transformation>
    <cl-transformation quality="auto" fetch-format="auto" width="500">
    </cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

This also works. But I want my width to be a variable, not a static width. So I updated the code to this:

```
<cl-image class="img-fluid" [public-id]="brand.image.publicId" dpr="auto" crop="scale" *ngIf="width">
    <cl-placeholder type="pixelate">
    </cl-placeholder>
    <cl-transformation [width]="width" crop="thumb">
    </cl-transformation>
    <cl-transformation quality="auto" fetch-format="auto" width="500">
    </cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

And this doesn't work. It displays the image, but it has not resized it, which is no good.
Notice this line:

```
<cl-transformation [width]="width" crop="thumb">
```

It's like it is being ignored, also I made sure the component is not being created until a width was set by using `*ngIf="width"`.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your app.component.ts, you can declare your variables e.g:

```
public imageHeight = "500";
public imageQuality = "50";
```

And then on your app.component.html, in your `cl-transformation` element, you will need to use the keyword `attr.`:

```
<cl-transformation
  attr.height="{{imagesize}}"
  crop="scale"
  attr.quality="{{imagequality}}"
>
```

[CodeSandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-poincare-loyir?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Cloudinary. and did not test it myslef. Looking at [Cloudinary code](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/tree/master/projects/angular-cld/src/lib), there are several options you can try:

1. Use the [`width` input](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/blob/dc438c2c792dc1371e35fa345b2a526c30be60b3/projects/angular-cld/src/lib/cloudinary-image.component.ts#L37) on the `cl-image` component. The component has definition for it

```js
export class CloudinaryImage
  implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input('public-id') publicId: string;
  @Input('client-hints') clientHints?: boolean;
  @Input('loading') loading: string;
  @Input('width') width?: string;
  @Input('height') height?: string;
```

2. If that is not what you are looking for, then looking at the [cl-transformation directive](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/blob/dc438c2c792dc1371e35fa345b2a526c30be60b3/projects/angular-cld/src/lib/cloudinary-transformation.directive.ts#L12), it seems you can only pass native attributes.

```js
export class CloudinaryTransformationDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  getAttributes(): NamedNodeMap {
    return this.el.nativeElement.attributes;
  }
}
```

Meaning that in order to transfer dynamic values to the directive element attribute, maybe you can use [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation#interpolation-).

```html
<cl-transformation width="{{ width }}" >
```

Comment: thanks for this, but I had already tried both of these and they don't work. I will set up a codepen or similar later to show my issue. If you try the cl-transformation, you get an error stating that there is no width parameter for cl-transformation.

Comment: Also, if you look at the input for the image, it's only ever used for the placeholder, which is not what I want

Comment: Not sure, but If you are trying to set native attribute on elements, maybe attribute bindigs `[attr.width]=""` can help you, or doing it programatically by getting the element view and doing nativeElement.setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Angular but you can try the following until someone more familiar comes along:

`<cl-transformation width={{width}} crop="thumb">`

Passing in a hard-coded integer works, so as long as `width` is defined and is an integer, it might work.

Comment: I have tried this, but all I get is this error: Can't bind to 'width' since it isn't a known property of 'cl-transformation'.